# No 'Network' in System Settings Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04 as a single-boot OS on my laptop. When I go to System Settings -> and type Network, nothing appears as in there's no Network option there. When I use the command

> gnome-control-center network

System Settings do appear, but without any Network icon. I am attaching the screenshot down below.

One thing to note is that, ever since I installed this copy of Ubuntu, I've been unable to connect to Wi-fi, sometimes it connects (but with extremely low strength) but most of the time doesn't. I can only run the internet from a pocket device that connects directly by means of a usb cable. Could this be somehow connected with the fact that I don't see any Network settings. Could anyone please help?

EDIT: [image: Screenshot]

Comment: You forgot to attach the screenshot.

Comment: I do want to point out that you are missing a lot of icons in your "System Settings", not just "Network".

Comment: Which other icons if I may ask? Should I re-install Ubuntu?

Comment: Take a look at https://itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/System_Settings_Ubuntu.jpeg.

Comment: oh god, I do seem to remember that they were there when I first installed it, at least brightness was. Could there be any specific reasons behind this that you can think of?